# Can Windows 10 digital license be used by Windows 11 at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, license

I'd like to try out the new Windows 11, but I don't want to loose my current Windows 10 Pro installation so I thought I buy another SSD to install W11 there and switch back if I'm not happy with it yet and some time later I try Win11 again.

The question is: if I did that and Win11 would activate based on my digital license will I be actually able to switch back to Win10 or will it be upgraded so that I loose it for Win10 and it'll be valid only for Win11?

Comment: You should be able to install Windows 11 in place and if you decide you don't like it, you can revert back to Windows 10 within 10 days (read [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/downgrade-from-windows-11-to-windows-10/84a2416d-ccfb-4d87-9eee-e1056591e91f)). But, if you are going to buy another SSD, I would do the following. Using `dd` in Linux live, create a clone of your current drive. Then go ahead and use the new SSD with Windows 11. Then, if you decide at anytime to go back to Windows 10 (on the same computer), your license should remain intact.

Comment: I just reread your initial question and I am not sure whether you can use them at the same time. If you are asking whether you can upgrade on one computer and use the other hard drive in another computer at the same time, the answer is, no. However, if you are merely switching between hard drives on the same computer, then MSFT activation servers are unlikely to raise a flag (and if they do, you should be able to reactivate either through their automated system or with the help of an agent if you describe that you are merely coming back to Windows 10 from the Windows 11 upgrade.

Comment: @Brian _if you are merely switching between hard drives on the same computer_ - that's exactly what I intend to do. With _at the same time_ I meant to have two activated Windowses, or reactivate them on switching hard drives, but actually using only one of them.

Comment: Based on historical experience with MSFT, most likely will be able to do that. When I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, I was able to revert back to using Windows 7 on the same machine. While this is no guarantee that MSFT won't one day change things, it is unlikely based on historical experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I did that and Win11 would activate based on my digital license will I be actually able to switch back to Win10 or will it be upgraded so that I loose it for Win10 and it'll be valid only for Win11?

Windows 11 will always be allowed to be activated with a Windows 10 license. Windows 11 was released as both an upgrade for Windows 10 and its eventual successor.

There is absolutely no reason you cannot dual boot to both Windows 10 and Windows 11 on the same machine. Windows users have been dual booting two Windows installations for decades without an issue.  Windows is activated on a machine basis even when dealing with a digital entitlement.

Due to the very nature of how the digital entitlement system works it would be nearly impossible for Microsoft to require multiple licenses to run individual licenses on the same machine. It’s not exactly straightforward to install a different edition than the edition that came with an OEM machine as it is.

Furthermore, a digital entitlement to your Windows 10 installation cannot be revoked simply by installing Windows 11 on another HDD.

Contrary to common belief, a Windows license doesn’t become invalid or otherwise unusable, a legitimate license can always be used. If it’s used to activate to many installations, the worse that will happen, it will require you to activate the installation by phone.

So will your existing installation of Windows become inactivated, it absolutely will not, even if it does you can always reactivate it.

Comment: I performend the experiment and it works exactly as you describe it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your Windows 10 license to upgrade to Windows 11 on the same machine as your Windows 10 and use both simultaneously at the same time. Windows will use the license to upgrade.

You can try dual boot to make it work, but dual boot (for me) is a lot of hassle.

Two ways forward:

1. Update to Windows 11 on this machine. I have been using Windows 11 Pro for 2 years and it works fine. You can always roll back if you do not like it or if there are issues.
2. Run a Windows 11 trial or additional license in a Virtual Machine and test it that way. You can compare side by side this way.

Comment: Windows 11 is currently free to update from an existing Windows 10 machine (assuming hardware specs are met) ([source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-windows-11?r=1#:~:text=How%20much%20does%20it%20cost,10%20in%20Settings%2FWindows%20Update.))

Comment: Yes, as I noted in step 1.

Comment: Your first line was, "You CANNOT use your Windows 10 license to upgrade to Windows 11 on the same machine"

Comment: Really? You suggest people to use Windows 11? Its horrible. Please let people decide for themselves if they want to use it or not. I tried it for a few weeks (I had to at work) before I finally was allowed to format and get back to Windows 10.

Comment: Brian - I meant both at the same time and clarified accordingly

Comment: LPChip - Windows 11 is working fine for me.

Comment: @LPChip let's not make it about which Windows is better here ;-] There are certainly good arguments for both sides. This thread it about licensing and experimenting with two hard drives.

Comment: @t3chb0t - If you want a definitive answer you should contact Microsoft. We can use our own experiences to answer a licensing question like this one

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, I guess you're right. I probably should google some hotline numbers and make absolutely sure that both installations will work before I start with this experiment.

Comment: Having two hard drives and switching betwen them would be quite like a dual-boot, but just a little bit more work and technically it's the same as having two OSes on the same HDD. You need one license to activate two installations so the original question should apply too.

Comment: @t3chb0t - You’ll probably have difficulty finding a number, activation hotline likely will be the closest to a definitive answer, Microsoft doesn’t actually provide technical support to the end users. It does provide technical support to those that purchase support contracts which is required for enterprise level licensing.